# Get points within a certain radius

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a latitude and longitude column in PostgreSQL. And I want to get all points with in a certain radius. I know their are libraries and extensions out there which can achieve this but I want to do it manually.
This is what I have done to get latitude and longitude from database:

```
lat1 = Places.query.with_entities(Places.latitude).all()
lon1 = Places.query.with_entities(Places.longitude).all()
```

Next I have written a function to get convert lat and long into distance in kilometers:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(lat1)):

    x = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(28.616700) - lat1[i]['latitude'])
    y = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(77.216700) - lon1[i]['longitude']) * Decimal(
    cos(lat1[i]['latitude'])) / Decimal(92.215)
    result.append(sqrt(x * x + y * y))
print result
```

How can I include the radius within which I want the points in this function.Also, as the output of lat1 and lon1 looks something like this:

```
{u'latitude': Decimal('28.633300')}
```

I find it difficult to convert and continuously getting error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'
```

I have creates a pastebin for lat1[lat1](https://pastebin.com/zu2QBs3d) and lon1[lon1](https://pastebin.com/t6uCDYMF) to show the exact output of lat1 and lon1.

Comment: You  `lon1` query should be referencing `Places.longitude` no?

Comment: Changed that. But this wan't causing the issue

Comment: is lat1 a list?

Comment: @Skyler it is a dict

Comment: Did you confirm by printing? you are calling .all() in query.  And is `i` an integer?

Comment: i is used to calculate distance iteratively. I have created a pastebin for lat1 and lon1

Comment: Please take a look at my answer

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha yeah for sure, but it helps to clear out the small stuff for these questions. Do make sure to accept and upvote the right answer if it comes around.

Comment: waiting for the right answer but @Skyler helped a lot

Comment: @Skyler I will upvote it for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your lat1 and lon1 are list of dictionaries. Therefore when you access their actual values do as following in your loop,

```
result = []
for i in range(len(lat1)):
    x = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(28.616700) - lat1[i]['latitude']);
    y = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(77.216700) - lon1[i]['longitude']) * Decimal(math.cos(lat1[i]['latitude'])) / Decimal(92.215);
    result.append(math.sqrt(x * x + y * y));
```

Following is the console output for an example case,

```
>>> lat1=[{u'latitude': Decimal('28.633300')}]
>>> lon1=[{u'longitude': Decimal('28.633300')}]
>>> x = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(28.616700) - lat1[0]['latitude']);
>>> y = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(77.216700) - lon1[0]['longitude']) * Decimal(math.cos(lat1[0]['latitude'])) / Decimal(92.215);
>>> result = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
>>> result
54.84298321157983
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict . Got this

Comment: Can you verify your answer with my pastebin output for lat1 and lon1

Comment: I updated the answer please take a look @RaghavPatnecha

Comment: Yours is working. But when I try to iterate I got an error. Check my code I have edited it according to your answer

Comment: What is `output`? shouldnt it be `len(lat1)` . also you'd want to replace lon1[0], lat1[0] with lon1[i] and lat1[i]. See my updated answer

Comment: output is same as lat1. Although for the clarity I have edited it. But still I am getting the same error

Comment: x = Decimal(111.12) * (Decimal(28.616700) - lat1[i]['latitude'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Ok, Can you print(lat1[0]) and show me the output. Seems you are not having a dictionary there.

Comment: (Decimal('28.633300'),)

Comment: So you have tuples instead of dictionaries. use lat1[i][0] instead of lat1[i]['latitude']. for lon1 see print(lon1[0]) and use either lon1[i][0] or lon1[i][1] depending on the output.

Comment: lat1[i][0] and lon1[i][0] is working fine but it suddenly gets stopped. I tried printing i and it only prints up to 10000 whereas len(lat1) is 11000. The Error now i am getting is TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Decimal' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Can you use my pastebin file and confirm your result

Comment: It seems your input has inconsistencies. Please try to fix that.

Comment: I can't figure out them. I am looking at this code from the past 6 hours